# How to get the correct Id parameter after saving on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have an SQL server DB currently working on a C# site, so I created a Laravel Project from scratch to use that DB. Everything is working and I can consult and write data on it, but the problem that I have is when I create a new object into a table I'm not getting the correct id parameter after the new Class function.

This is my Controller:

```
$softwareRequest = new SoftwareRequest;
    $softwareRequest->OwnerManager = $request->input('contactApplicationManager');
    $softwareRequest->TestorName = $request->input('contactTesterRequestedBy');
    $softwareRequest->TestorPhone = $request->input('contactTesterPhone');
    $softwareRequest->TestorEmail = $request->input('contactTesterEmail');

    $softwareRequest->save();
```

if I DD() the variable **$softwareRequest** I get:

```
#attributes: array:5 [▼
"OwnerEmail" => "test@test.com"
"TestorName" => "Testor Name"
"TestorPhone" => "3456787455"
"TestorEmail" => "test1@test.com"
"Id" => 57980
```

the Id on the database is set to **Id** (the I in Uppercase) instead of id but the Id parameter I get after saving is not the correct one (not even close), once I go to the DB to check manually, it did stored the data with the correct Id number, since I'm using eloquent and I created the models for each table, how can I get the correct Id parameter for the new saved data right after I ->save()  ? I need to get the Id right after saving because I need to use it to store something else on another table.

This is what the model has:

```
protected $table = 'SoftwareRequest';
protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
public $timestamps = false;
```

I put primary key as Id since that's the way it is set in the DB, if I take away the line

```
protected $primaryKey = 'Id';
```

I get the same but **id** with lowercase

```
#attributes: array:5 [▼
"OwnerEmail" => "test@test.com"
"TestorName" => "Testor Name"
"TestorPhone" => "3456787455"
"TestorEmail" => "test1@test.com"
"id" => 57981
```

but again, that's not even close on the correct Id it should get, the increment next number is 5917, I think the problem might be more on that the tables are hard coded on the models, any idea?

Comment: Do `$id = $softwareRequest->save():` and that'll give you the new record's id (which should be the same value you're seeing when you do `dd()`. If that value isnt what you expect, its almost certainly that the value you're looking for it to be is wrong, not the value its giving you.

Comment: Why exactly do you expect the value to be `5917`?

Comment: @WesleySmith `save` returns a `bool`

Comment: @WesleySmith I do get the same record and I expect the value to be 5917 because I go to the database and look for the last record and the Id is 5916

Comment: @pacokent go to your database and create a new record by hand and see what 'id' you get

Comment: @lagbox, bahh, indeed! my bad

Comment: @WesleySmith I think I know whats the problem, as I described, the database already exists and it's working on a prod .net site. To be honest I'm not that familiar to use Laravel and SQL server DB but I noticed there is a table called, SoftwareRequest_ChangeLog and it creates a record every time I save something on the table SoftwareRequest :S and the Id I'm getting on the code on the top, is the last id record from that changelog table. Maybe it has something to do with how the DB is set. Thanks a lot for your replay :)

Comment: @lagbox looks like is the DB and how it is set, a record in a changelog table is beign created automatically after saving on the DB and that's the Id i'm getting :S

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how its inserting that other record. It could be a after insert trigger or it could be handled in php, perhaps by overwritting the model's save method. If the later is true, I guess its possible that code is saving the log record and incorrectly setting $model-Id's value to that id, but we'd need to see that code to know

Comment: the way it gets the 'id' after insert is by using the "last insert id" so in this "transaction"(for lack of a better word) the last inserted id is from the second table (which an insert happens to log the action) ... though i am not that familiar with sql server

Comment: @WesleySmith as far I see, the other record is being inserted by the same DB in SQL server, maybe that was set when they first created that DB, but i'm not familiar with SQL server, I googled and I see that there are options to create a record on a specific table after saving on another. funny thing is that laravel is getting the Id from that record and not from the one just saved :/

Comment: @lagbox you are right and also i'm not that familiar with SQL server, what I will do to solve this is after saving the record, I'll search for it with $softwareRequest_id = SoftwareRequest::where('RequestNo', $softwareRequest->RequestNo)->first();              then get the Id $softwareRequest_id->Id              that works, that's the only way I can think right now. thanks for answering

Comment: that is just my guess what is happening but it seems to make sense, good luck, let us know what you find :)

Comment: some reference for you https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/32883  https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/33430

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$softwareRequest =SoftwareRequest::create([

  'OwnerManager' = $request->input('contactApplicationManager'),
 'TestorName' = $request->input('contactTesterRequestedBy'),
 'TestorPhone' = $request->input('contactTesterPhone'),
'TestorEmail' = $request->input('contactTesterEmail'),
]);
```

Then:

```
dd($softwareRequest);
```